# Ошибка "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект"

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет Всем! Что означает

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "WindowsApplication1.Form1.textBox1" требуется ссылка на объект   `C:\Users\Владик\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 71` 13  WindowsFormsApplication1

Код

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show();
                Form1.textBox1.Text = "text";
```

Ошибка в чём?

Comment: попробуйте:

    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    this.textBox1.Text = "text";

Comment: Не,тот textbox1 находится в 1 форме я хочу с 2 формы передать данные в textbox1 первой формы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, самый простой, это сменить модификатор доступа textBox что не есть хорошо, т.е. с privat на public

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

Лично я использую интерфейс, в котором реализую нужные мне свойства, события, etc...
Привязываю к классу, и

```
Form2 form = new Form2(this);
```

Думаю в интернете много инфы на эту тему, погуглите.

Comment: Не лучший вариант. Не есть хорошо предоставлять прямой доступ к начинке класса.

Comment: Я же написал, что это плохо, но оценив возможности ТС-са это первое что пришло в голову.

Comment: @Dexter а что плохого он только предоставляет доступ к паблик методам, что в этом плохого?

Comment: Мне кажется @Dexter не очень разбирается в c#...

Answer (score 1):

Вы вообще понимаете что делаете? Form1 это класс, у вас должна быть ссылка на экземпляр первой формы. То есть можно его передавать как делегат (не путать с шарповскими делегатами), например в конструкторе

```
private Form1 delForm1;
public void Form2(Form1 delForm1) {
this.delForm1 = delForm1;
}

public void Foo() {
delForm1.ChangeText(this.textBox1.text);
}
```

А в классе Form1

```
public void ChangeText(string text) {
textBox1.text = text;
}
```

Comment: а я всгда так делал:

    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.Owner = this;
    f.ShowDialog();

в Form2:
  
    Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;

- [Form.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx)

Comment: @Spectre, сорри я джавист)